# How to add labels to Flink kubernetes operator deployment CRD?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I deployed Flink kubernetes operator and while deploying Custom resource for 'FlinkDeployment', I need to add few metadata labels to the deployment spec because our organization has an admission webhook that validates custom labels like 'app_id', 'env' etc. to be in the deployment object. Is there a way to add metadata.labels to the FlinkDeployment CRD? CRD is https:/github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/main/helm/flink-kubernetes-operator/crds/flinkdeployments.flink.apache.org-v1.yml

Error in operator logs deploying FlinkDeployment job:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.kuberntes.shaded.io.fabric8.kuberntes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://10.19.0.1/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/xxx/deployments. Message: Forbidden! Configured service account doesn'ta have access.  Admission webhook "validation_gk.sh" denied the request: [deployment-must-have-cc] All deployments must have 'app_name', 'env' label set.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is by downloading the helm chart and adding the labels directly on the file and then installing that helm on your k8s cluster.

I also see that the values.yaml of that Helm chart has values for setting labels on the operatorPod, but it's only for the [flink operator deployment](https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/f2c34abc466c9e33745a9b2b62e4ac2ad640ef39/helm/flink-kubernetes-operator/templates/flink-operator.yaml)

Comment: I tried exactly that on examples/basic.yaml by adding labels under metadata section.However, when operator send the request to deployment API endpoint, for some reason it's not validating it. As you pointed out, setting labels on operatorPod works but not Flinkdeployment.

Comment: @Gladiator So you were able to add the labels then? My suggestion was to edit the file you needed (https:/github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/main/helm/flink-kubernetes-operator/crds/flinkdeployments.flink.apache.org-v1.yml) after you download the chart, you can just add the label directly on that yaml and then deploy the Helm chart.

Comment: Can we add to the CRD's OpenAPIV3 schema spec to associate with values for labels to dynamically pick from Flinkdeployments? Since the CRD is at cluster level and I need the deployments at multiple namespaces with different label values, I didn't hard code the label values.